# Errno 32 Broken pipe error with multiprocessing.Queue

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, pipe

I'm trying to scrape some webpages and given that each webpage takes about 2s and I have 20k of them, I decided to use the **multiprocessing** library to create several processes to scrape the webpages simultaneously.

The setup I have is a pandas dataframe with previously parsed data and a "new data" dictionary. Since I don't know whether I need to scrape the webpage or if it's already been scraped, I created a **multiprocessing.Queue** instance, together with a **multiprocessing.Manager.dict()**. I have a function, *queueFill*, that verifies whether the data is in the dataframe and if not, places the link in question in the multiprocessing.Queue instance. There's also a function that can get items from the multiprocessing.Queue, *getData*, that takes one link from the queue, downloads and parses it and adds it to the "new data" dictionary.

I am trying to create a process that does the *queueFill* function and one that does the *getData* function:

```
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
newPlayersDict = manager.dict()
errorsDict = manager.dict()
i=0
linklen = str(len(linklist))
q = multiprocessing.Queue()


if 'playersDF' in globals():
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=queueFill,args=(playersDF,q,linklist))
else:
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=queueFill,args=(None,q,linklist))

p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=getData,args=(q,newPlayersDict,errorsDict,linklen,i))
time.sleep(0.5)
p1.start()
p2.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()
```

However, running this gives me a **[Errno 32] Broken pipe** on the line:

```
p1.start()
```

I don't understand why this is happening. Even if the *queueFill* function is modified to immediately return, the error still occurs. Could someone help me understand why this error is happening, and how I should fix it?

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question, so that future people can keep their sanity:

It turns out multiprocessing doesn't really like being run in an IPython/Jupyter notebook. Upon moving the code to a separate standalone script with the __name__ check, the output was as expected.